# Ember.js 4.4 classic template syntax

Tags: javascript, ember.js, upgrade, octane

I would like to update a project built in Ember 3.28 without Octane to version 4.4.

I tried using `ember-cli-update` to change version and now all sorts of errors are thrown, such as template properties that must be used with `@` and curly brackets components no longer supported...

I am new to Ember and I haven't understood if it is still possible to use the classic syntax on 4.4, if so, how can I continue to use the classic syntax? Especially on templates.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

> I am new to Ember

Hello! and welcome!!

---

> is still possible to use the classic syntax on 4.4,

it is not possible to use *some* classic syntax after Ember 4.0.

In particular, when you have `{{theseThings}}` you must:

- have `theseThings` defined in scope (like in strict mode, or via `let`, or component yield)

  ```
  {{#let ... as |theseThings|}}
     {{theseThings}}
  {{/let}}
  ```

  or

  ```
  <Foo as |theseThings|>
    {{theseThigs}}
  </Foo>
  ```
- change the invocation to be declared as an:

  - argument (prepend a `@`, so `{{@theseThings}}`)
  - local variable on "the context" (this / the class instance), so: `{{this.theseThings}}`

There is a codemod to help out with these things, but it's a bit finnicky, and you'll want to go file-by-file:

- https://github.com/ember-codemods/ember-no-implicit-this-codemod
- https://github.com/ember-codemods/ember-angle-brackets-codemod/